# i use mariaDB and i broken

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE account
(
    user_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    passwd VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    name NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    phone_num VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    business_num VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY('user_id')
) DEFAULT CHARSET='utf8';
```

i set this sql 
but doesn't work

and write this error code in my console

**"ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''user_id')
) DEFAULT CHARSET='utf8'' at line 7"**

what i'm wrong? i just see internet and write code!

what's problem? i didn't show any problem DEFAULT CHARSET!

please help me

Comment: Either backticks, or no quotes at all `PRIMARY KEY(`user_id`)`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

```
CREATE TABLE account
(
user_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
passwd VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
name NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
phone_num VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
business_num VARCHAR(20)
)DEFAULT CHARSET='utf8';
```

Test with [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/760bc). (MySQL, but that should not make a difference here...)

Comment: i just use 'name' now use name